# How can I check if input is <=2 or undefined with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

The **length <= 2 check** is **working** ONLY if I'm manually erasing the text from the input.
However, My input has closing button which has reset(); on it, and when I'm pressing it, my input is empty, however jquery code doesnt care about that and doesnt recognise the input as empty, because as I know the reset(); function turns my input form to undefined.. so I have to check the input for undefined in my jQuery, however it doesn't work. any clues??

```
<script>
    $('.regulator').keyup(function() {
      
      if ($(this).val().length <= 2 || $(this).val().value == undefined) {
        $('.quickSearchResults').hide();
      }  else {
        $('.quickSearchResults').show();
      }
    }).keyup();
    </script>
```

Comment: `$(this).val().value ` makes no sense. val() returns a string, it does not have a value property.

Comment: I tried to do:  if ($(this).val().length <= 2 || typeof $(this).val() == "undefined") ..  but that doesnt work, maybe a syntax problem?

Comment: Only reason .val() is going to return undefined if the element does not exist. If the user is typing in it, it is going to exist. There is no reason to check for it. The check would be `var val = $(this).val(); if (val === undefined || val.length <=2) {}`

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use this instead:

1. use .on("input" since it handles paste too
2. reuse the toggle function on click, on input and on load
3. add a timeout on the reset

```js
$(function() {
  const $reg = $('.regulator');
  const $qs = $('.quickSearchResults');
  const $rst = $("#rst");
  const toggleQS = () => {
    const val = $reg.val();
    $qs.toggle(val.length > 2);
  };
  $reg.on("input", toggleQS);
  $rst.on("click", () => setTimeout(toggleQS,10));
  toggleQS(); // in case there is data already
})
```

```css
.quickSearchResults {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <input class="regulator" id="someId" name="someName" value="More than 2" />
  <input type="reset" id="rst" />
</form>
<div class="quickSearchResults">Results</div>
```

Comment: the Reset button should be empty i guess? I don't want to display "More than 2" in it..   Also may I ask why my version is not good? If i only could check the input for undefined value.. then the problem will be resolved...

Answer (score 1):

There is really no reason to check for undefined if you are using the value of the input the user is typing in. `.val()` is not going to return undefined when the user is interacting with it.

```
$('.regulator').keyup(function() {
  
  if ($(this).val().length <= 2) {
    $('.quickSearchResults').hide();
  }  else {
    $('.quickSearchResults').show();
  }
}
```

Now if you really want to check for undefined, do that check first

```
$('.regulator').keyup(function() {
  var val = $(this).val()
  if (val === undefined || val.length <= 2) {
    $('.quickSearchResults').hide();
  }  else {
    $('.quickSearchResults').show();
  }
}
```

how most people would code this

```
$('.regulator').on('input', function() {
    $('.quickSearchResults').toggle(val.length > 2);
}).trigger('input');
```

Now to handle reset, listen to the event.

```
$('#yourForm').on("reset", function () {
  $('.quickSearchResults').hide();
});
```

or

```
$('#yourForm').on("reset", function () {
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    $('.regulator').trigger('input');
  });
});
```

Comment: I know that if I'm writing a new code, I need to do it that way. The problem is that I'm trying to get a result while there are limitations. The problem is with the jquery code that I can't change, its locked. so, to get it working i'm trying to "hide" and "show" the div instead of changing the jquery code. a little manipulation. My search input has cache function, I don't know if I can change that with writing another function. can I?

Comment: No clue without seeing all the code. This just fixes the issues in your code you posted above. I assume if you are using some sort of library to search maybe it has a configuration to do some things.